# Return first row number for max date

Tags: excel, vba, range

How do I write VBA to return the first row number found in column L for the max date in that column?

I'm trying this code and get

> "Object variable or With block variable not set"

```vb
Sub FindMaxValRow()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim MaxCell As Range
Dim MaxVal As Long

Set Rng = Range("L1:L500")
MaxVal = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
Set MaxCell = Rng.find(what:=MaxVal, LookIn:=xlValues)
MsgBox "Maximum value found at row " & MaxCell.Row
End Sub
```

Comment: It mean MaxCell is Nothing. I guess the data on column L is date. Please try `Dim MaxVal As Date  
    MaxVal = Format(WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng), "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using formula it would be

```
=MATCH(MAX(L:L),L:L,0)
```

IF you want to calculate it in VBA then you can use the Evaluate method:

```
evaluate("=MATCH(MAX(L:L),L:L,0)")
```

Comment: Evaluate works great!

Sub FindMaxValRow()
Dim MaxVal As Integer

MaxVal = Evaluate("=MATCH(MAX(L:L),L:L,0)")

MsgBox MaxVal

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

### Identify the Row of the First Occurrence of a Date

- Column `L` has dates (and empty cells)
- Column `M` has the formula `=L2` in the 2nd row copied down (added for the test)
- Column `N` has the spilling formula `=L2:L10` in the 2nd row (added for the test)

[image]

**Application vs WorksheetFunction**

The `Max` (and e.g. `Sum`...) function will fail if there are error values in the range. So will the `Match` (or e.g. `VLookup`) function if no match was found. If you use their early-bound (`WorksheetFunction`) version, a run-time error will occur. To avoid this, you should use their late-bound (`Application`) versions to be able to test their result with the `IsNumeric` or the `IsError` functions.

**Match**

- When you're looking for the first (in this case top-most) value in a single-column range, instead of the `Find` method, you should use the more efficient `Application.Match` function.
- If (since) the value is a date, `Match` will convert it to an integer (whole number). The *CLng* function is used just to emphasize this.
- This works for values, formulas, and spilling formulas.

```vb
Sub IdentifyRowOfMaxDateMATCH()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Identify Row of Max Date Using 'Match'"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("L2:L500")
    
    Dim MaxValue As Variant: MaxValue = Application.Max(rg)
    
    If IsError(MaxValue) Then
        MsgBox "Found error values in range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) & """.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim RowIndex: RowIndex = Application.Match(CLng(MaxValue), rg, 0)
    
    Dim maxCell As Range:
    If IsNumeric(RowIndex) Then
        Set maxCell = rg.Cells(RowIndex)
    End If
    
    If maxCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Maximum date """ & CDate(MaxValue) & """ not found.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox "Maximum date """ & CDate(MaxValue) _
            & """ found in (worksheet) row " & maxCell.Row & ".", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If

End Sub
```

**Find**

- If you insist on using the `Find` method, you need to convert the value to a string with the following pattern:

  ```
  "mm\/dd\/yyyy"
  ```

  using the `\/` separator, making it locale-independent.
- This works for values, formulas, and spilling formulas.

```vb
Sub IdentifyRowOfMaxDateFIND()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Identify Row of Max Date Using 'Find'"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("L2:L500")
    
    Dim MaxValue As Variant: MaxValue = Application.Max(rg)
    
    If IsError(MaxValue) Then
        MsgBox "Found error values in range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) & """.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim MaxDateString As String:
    MaxDateString = Format(MaxValue, "mm\/dd\/yyyy")
    
    Dim maxCell As Range:
    Set maxCell = rg.Find(What:=MaxDateString, _
        After:=rg.Cells(rg.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If maxCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Maximum date """ & CDate(MaxDate) & """ not found.", _
           vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox "Maximum date """ & CDate(MaxDate) _
            & """ found in (worksheet) row " & maxCell.Row & ".", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If

End Sub
```

**Match vs Find**

- `Match` is more efficient (faster) than `Find`.
- Looking at the screenshot, `Match` will identify row 6 no matter what i.e. even if row 6 is hidden or it is hidden using `AutoFilter`. The same will happen if you use `Find` with a date and `xlFormulas` or `xlFormulas2` (see the test below) but you can only use this if the cells contain values.
- On the other hand, if row 6 is hidden or hidden by `AutoFilter`, `Find` with the value formatted as a string (`MaxDateString`) and `xlValues`, will identify row 8 (see above and below).

**The Test**

```vb
Sub FindDateTest()
    
    Dim Ins(): Ins = VBA.Array(xlValues, xlFormulas, xlFormulas2)
    Dim Ats(): Ats = VBA.Array(xlWhole, xlPart)
    Dim Offsets(): Offsets = VBA.Array(0, 1, 2)
    Dim Contents():
    Contents = VBA.Array("Values", "Formulas", "A formula spilling")
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    Dim rg As Range, maxCell As Range, MaxValue, DateString As String

    Dim FindValues(), FindValue, i As Long, a As Long, o As Long, f As Long

    For o = 0 To UBound(Offsets)
        
        Set rg = ws.Range("L2:L10").Offset(, Offsets(o))
        MaxValue = Application.Max(rg)
        FindValues = VBA.Array( _
            CDate(MaxValue), _
            CLng(MaxValue), _
            Format(MaxValue, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") _
            )
        
        Debug.Print String(80, "-")
        Debug.Print Contents(o) & " in range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) & """"
        Debug.Print String(80, "-")
        Debug.Print "Value (TypeName, Vartype)", "Found ", _
            "Lookin", "LookAt", "Cell"
        
        For f = 0 To UBound(FindValues)
            
            FindValue = FindValues(f)
            DateString = FindValue & " (" _
                & TypeName(FindValue) & ", " & VarType(FindValue) & ")"
        
            For i = 0 To UBound(Ins)
                For a = 0 To UBound(Ats)
                    On Error Resume Next
                        Set maxCell = rg.Find(What:=FindValue, _
                            After:=rg.Cells(rg.Cells.Count), _
                            LookIn:=Ins(i), LookAt:=Ats(a))
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    
                    If maxCell Is Nothing Then
                        Debug.Print DateString, "No    ", _
                            Ins(i), Ats(a)
                    Else
                        Debug.Print DateString, "Yes   ", _
                            Ins(i), Ats(a), maxCell.Address(0, 0)
                        Set maxCell = Nothing
                    End If
                Next a
            Next i
            
        Next f
    
    Next o

End Sub
```

**The Test Result**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Values in range "L2:L500"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Value (TypeName, Vartype)   Found         Lookin        LookAt        Cell
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4163          1 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4163          2 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         Yes           -4123          1            L6
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         Yes           -4123          2            L6
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         Yes           -4185          1            L6
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         Yes           -4185          2            L6
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4163          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4163          2 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4123          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4123          2 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4185          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4185          2 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      Yes           -4163          1            L6
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      Yes           -4163          2            L6
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4123          1 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4123          2 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4185          1 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4185          2 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Formulas in range "M2:M500"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Value (TypeName, Vartype)   Found         Lookin        LookAt        Cell
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4163          1 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4163          2 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4123          1 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4123          2 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4185          1 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4185          2 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4163          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4163          2 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4123          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4123          2 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4185          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4185          2 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      Yes           -4163          1            M6
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      Yes           -4163          2            M6
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4123          1 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4123          2 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4185          1 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4185          2 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A formula spilling in range "N2:N500"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Value (TypeName, Vartype)   Found         Lookin        LookAt        Cell
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4163          1 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4163          2 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4123          1 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4123          2 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4185          1 
6.8.2023. (Date, 7)         No            -4185          2 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4163          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4163          2 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4123          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4123          2 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4185          1 
45144 (Long, 3)             No            -4185          2 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      Yes           -4163          1            N6
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      Yes           -4163          2            N6
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4123          1 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4123          2 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4185          1 
08/06/2023 (String, 8)      No            -4185          2
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an ancient problem with the date formatting, the local number formatting and the find method of VBA, which originate somewhere the comparing of the values when you see something else in a cell then the really stored value.
Don't ask why, but this code works

```
Set MaxCell = Rng.find(what:=CDate(MaxVal), LookIn:=xlFormulas)
```

In this case doesn't matter the displayed instantiation of the date.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware you can get that information, using this formula?

```
=ROW(INDEX(B$3:B$11,MATCH(MAX(B$3:B$11),B$3:B$11,0)))
```

Let me explain how it works:

- `MAX(B$3:B$11)` calculates the maximum value.
- `MATCH(MAX(B$3:B$11),B$3:B$11,0)` finds that maximum value in that list (using '0' for "exact match").
- `INDEX(...)` finds the index of that found maximum value within that same array.
- `ROW(...)`. Well, that's obvious :-)

Have fun